# Show/Hide Fields based on criteria

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint custom list where I'm using SPD to control the form. Is there code I can write to hide a text field until 'Field 1' = 'Other'?

Field 1 is a choice field= (Yes, No, Other)

If a user selects 'Other' then the text field would appear for them to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

Test code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     showOrHide() ;
     $("select[title='Field 1']").change(function () {
         showOrHide();
         
     });
 });
function showOrHide(){
if ($("[title='Field 1'] option:selected").text() != "Other") {
             $('nobr:contains("text")').closest('tr').hide();
            
         }
         else {
             $('nobr:contains("text")').closest('tr').show();
             
         }
}
</script>
```

Test result:
[image]